# User Input Query

Tags: sql, oracle, sqlplus

I'm having some issues with this Query. 
I am trying to create a query where the user will be able to input 2 dates at runtime. It's asking me for an input, for both start date and end sate, but, it then comes up with: `ORA-00904: "JAN": invalid identifier`

My Query is currently:

```
SELECT p.FirstName, p.email, a.Avatar_Name, s.Species_Name, a.Avatar_Level, a.Skill, s.Wisdom_Level, a.AvA_DOB, a.Hoard
    FROM Players P, Avatars A, Species S
    WHERE a.Player_ID = p.Player_ID
    AND a.Species_ID = s.Species_ID
    AND Avatar_Level = 'Master'
    AND AvA_DOB BETWEEN &startdate AND &enddate
    ORDER BY Hoard DESC;
```

I want the user to be able to find a list of avatars between the two dates the user enters. 
Any help please? If more information is needed please do ask! (:
(SQL PLUS)

Comment: And these various issues are...?

Comment: What error is sqlplus returning?

Comment: Well, it's asking me for an input, for both start date and end sate, but, it then comes up with:
ORA-00904: "JAN": invalid identifier

Comment: My DATE is dd-mmm-yyyy format, so like 10-JAN-2014 if thats any help

Comment: Put them in single quotes. '10-JAN-2014'

Comment: As Bob said, you should have single quotes around your substitution variables and you should consider to_date function (to avoid implicit casting).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Date values in SQL need to be wrapped in single quotes.  Oracle will cast these strings to a date datatype, but it's safer to use an explicit conversion, with the expected format mask.

```
SELECT p.FirstName, p.email, a.Avatar_Name, s.Species_Name, a.Avatar_Level, a.Skill, s.Wisdom_Level, a.AvA_DOB, a.Hoard
    FROM Players P, Avatars A, Species S
    WHERE a.Player_ID = p.Player_ID
    AND a.Species_ID = s.Species_ID
    AND Avatar_Level = 'Master'
    AND AvA_DOB BETWEEN to_date('&startdate', 'dd-mmm-yyyy') 
                AND to_date('&enddate', 'dd-mmm-yyyy')
    ORDER BY Hoard DESC;
```

Comment: Yes, thank-you for the answer. I did actually figure this out when I re-looked at it, I just had a reminder by Bob haha! Thank-you anyhow.